# Acknowledging Teltonika GPS Device after receiving IMEI using php

Tags: php, gps, php-socket

Hi please any one can explain how to send acknowledgment from server to Teltonika GPS device? The GPS device is sending IMEI (International Mobile Equipment Identity ) number and once I get IMEI number the packet is waiting for acknowledgment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send a data like

```
01 // means send data to server
00 // stop sending data to server

pack("H*", "01");
```

Comment: Much simplier would be sending just `"\x00"` or `"\x01"` instead of using pack for that.